# Hints to read and save to database

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, data-binding

I'm doing a C# course this summer and in the current task I'm going to work with a database. Very interesting and I'm eager to get working, but I'm totally lost right now(perhaps my blood suger is low)! According to the demands of the task, I must use a disconnected approach using DataSets or dataTables, DataAdapters and CommandBuilders to load the a copy of the database into memory to work with it(open, read and close) and then when I want to update the database, do the opposite(open, save and close)

I have created a SQL Server 2008 database and I have also created a table. Hmmm, now what!? I guess I have to begin to connect to the database and select the table. It's from here and forward that I would apreciate some hints. Looking forward to get starting! Thanks!

Comment: Your question is vague - can you please be more specific?  "Appreciate some hints" doesn't help us.  Do you just want to know how to connect?

Comment: Some help to connect would be nice, but also how to read and write to a copy of the database

Comment: Start with entity framework!! (www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/net30/article.php/c15489/ADONET-Entity-Framework-Tutorial-and-Basics.htm) :-)

Comment: @pro - Bad idea, this guys "task" is to use DataSets or DataTables. My tutors didn't tend to like it if I did something off-task, even if it was better...

Comment: First thing what students suppose to learn in schools is TO LEARN. So you can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655891(v=vs.90)), [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C), and even [here](http://www.google.com/)

Comment: Besides staying on his professor's topic, it's always better to know WHY something works before taking the shortcut/lazy way of using Entity Framework.

Comment: I'd say the learning curve of Entity Framework is a little steep if we are still in the 'how do I connect to a database' stage. I'd start with using SqlConnection/SqlCommand etc then work up to Entity Framework later

Comment: An easy way is to use a [`TableAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx(v=vs.100).aspx). In Visual Studio, add a `DataSet` to your project, go to the `Server Explorer`, connect to your database, and drag-and-drop your table into your `DataSet`. In your code, create an instance of your `DataSet` and `TableAdapter`, call the fill method of the `TableAdapter`, magic done... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on two parameters

```
1. your amount of data has to update

2. the update frequency
```

If you feel that these two parameters are important and can slow your application, then uses the offline mode.

the amount of data can mitigate the bandwidth

Below an example

```
    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    var dataSet = new DataSet();

    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Your query", connection);
        adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        connection.Close();

        //Print results  
        for (i = 0; i <= dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[1].ItemArray[1].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can connect by using a [`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) object.  This is located in the [`System.Data.SqlClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t72t3k4) namespace.  You will want to become familiar with those objects when you are working disconnected or connected.  There's some sample code in the links that I've provided.

You'll need a connection string to pass to the constructor.  If your database is running locally it *might* look like this.

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TheNameOfYourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   connection.Open();
}
```

It's as simple as that.  Since the object implements `IDisposable`, you can use the `using` statement so that the object handles clean-up appropriately (in this case, by default, the connection will return to the connection pool).

After that, you can take a look at `SqlCommand` so you can start issuing commands against your database.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have several approaches available.
Starting with DataReader and DBCommand, all the way up to ORMs Entity framework and POCO.
As you step up the abstractions levels they do more and more for you, but giving you less and less scope to do what you want unless you know the basics.

If I were you I'd start at the bottom of the ladder

That's SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlParameter and SqlDataReader

Don't go down the Wally the Wizard, click a button and Visual Studio does it all for you route. They are for two types of people, ones who know waht they are doing, and ones who don't want to know...

Loads of tutorials about, but if I were you. I'd get a decent programming with C# book, turn to the chapter on databases and read and do, read again do again. The people who find this stuff really hard, are the ones who didn't bother doing that.

When you've done that, you'll know enough to come back and ask decent questions if you need to.